# How can i use two buttons in setOnDragListener?

Tags: java, android

I'm new in Android Studio, i know some basics about it and java. I'm not an expert. I'm doing a drag and drop game and i want to drag and drop two items, the code is working, but i need to check that a button is on a specific linear layout but both buttons are validated.

This is for Android Studio

```
package com.example.lalo.menuhamburguesa;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.content.ClipData;

import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;



public class Fragment3 extends Fragment {
    Button dragbutton;
    Button dragbutton1;
    LinearLayout dropbutton;
    LinearLayout dropbutton1;
    TextView textView, sucess;
    TextView textView1, sucess1;
    int total, fail = 0;
    int total1, fail1 = 0;

    @Override
    /*public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment3, container, false);
    }*/

    /*View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2, container, false);
    pdfViewer = (PDFView) v.findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        pdfViewer.fromAsset("Ejercicios.pdf").pages(0).load();*/


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
/*
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

With this:

return new SampleView(R.layout.activity_main);
*/
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment3, container, false);


        dragbutton = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.one);
        dropbutton = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.drag_it_linear);

        dragbutton1 = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.one1);
        dropbutton1 = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.drag_it_linear1);


        textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Total);
        sucess = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Success);

        textView1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Total1);
        sucess1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.Success1);


        //================================================LISTENER========================


        dropbutton.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final int action = event.getAction();
                switch (action) {
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
// Executed after startDrag() is called.
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                        // Executed after the Drag Shadow enters the drop area
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP: {
                        //Executed when user drops the data
                        fail = fail + 1;
                        return (true);
                    }
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: {
                        total = total + 1;
                        int value = total - fail;
                        sucess.setText("Sucessful Drops:" + value);
                        textView.setText("Total Drops: " + total);
                        return (true);
                    }
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
        dragbutton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(dragbutton);
                v.startDrag(data, shadow, null, 0);
                return false;
            }
        });



        //================================================LISTENER========================

        //================================================LISTENER========================


        dropbutton1.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final int action = event.getAction();

                //CASE


                switch (action) {
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
// Executed after startDrag() is called.
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                        // Executed after the Drag Shadow enters the drop area
                        break;
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP: {
                        //Executed when user drops the data
                        fail1 = fail1 + 1;
                        return (true);
                    }
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: {
                        total1 = total1 + 1;
                        int value1 = total1 - fail1;
                        sucess1.setText("Sucessful Drops:" + value1);
                        textView1.setText("Total Drops: " + total1);
                        return (true);
                    }
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                //CASE

                return true;
            }
        });
        dragbutton1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
                View.DragShadowBuilder shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(dragbutton1);
                v.startDrag(data, shadow, null, 0);
                return false;
            }
        });



        //================================================LISTENER========================


        return v;
    }
}
```

I expect only one validation for each setOnDragListener but i get two

Answer (score 0):

both  your drag buttons are returning false though they consume the onTouch action. See what happens if you make them return true.